# Text of JTextArea not being retrieved?

Tags: java

I want to get the text of private access JTextArea from another class in the same package and store/save the text into a String.

```
public class JTextAreaDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public JTextAreaDemo() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    TxtArea_Class d = new TxtArea_Class();
    d.readJtxtAreaText();


}

public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JTextAreaDemo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;  

 /**
 * @return the jTextArea1
 */
 public String getjTextArea1() {
    return jTextArea1.getText();
}

/**
 * @param jTextArea1 the jTextArea1 to set
 */
public void setjTextArea1(javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1) {
    this.jTextArea1 = jTextArea1;
}
```

Now I want to save the text of JTextArea to string in below class

```
public class TxtArea_Class {

JTextAreaDemo demo;
String txt;

public TxtArea_Class(){

   demo = new JTextAreaDemo(); 
   txt = new String();
}

public void readJtxtAreaText(){

    txt = demo.getjTextArea1();

    if(txt.isEmpty()){

        System.out.println("Failed To Get TextArea Contents ");
    }
    else{

        System.out.println("Successfully Get TextArea Contents ");

    }


}
```

Console Output :

```
Failed to Get TextArea Contents
```

Comment: private members can't be accessed from outside the class. Even not from  derived/child class.

Comment: I have read the earlier posts regarding this question but the jtxtarea is public threir. I am focused to work with setters and getters rather but they are not working for me.

Comment: Private accessors are not the issue here. The line `if(txt.isEmpty())` will always return true, because you did not set the text anywhere and the text is an empty string "".

Comment: In `JTextAreaDemo`, provide a `getter` which returns a `String`, in this getter simply return the results of the `getText` method from the `JTextArea`

Comment: private members can't be directly accessible from outside the class wheras they are accessible via getters and setters.

Comment: Use getter and Setter methods and make them public

Comment: can you provide code, how  you initializing jtextArea?

Comment: I have uploaded the full code of both classes above. JTextAreaDemo is gui form which contains private JTextArea. I have provided public getter and setter in JTextAreaDemo. So when user enter text into JTextArea a gui component. So it will initialize through setter.

Comment: when this function "jButton1ActionPerformed()"get Invocked?

Comment: I got the issue, make following changes in your "TxtArea_Class" class. 

public TxtArea_Class(JTextAreaDemo demo) {
this.demo = demo;
 str = new String();
}

and in jButton1ActionPerformed() {
 TxtArea_Class d = new TxtArea_Class(this);
    d.readJtxtAreaText();

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your `TextArea_Calss's` constructor

try the following.

```
public TextArea_class(TextAreaDemo demo) {
  this.demo = demo;
  this.str = new String();
}
```

and in button event. do this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    TxtArea_Class d = new TxtArea_Class(this);
    d.readJtxtAreaText();


}
```

In current implementation, Every-time you create an instance of `TextArea-calss` a new frame get created. because in TextArea_Class constructor you are creating an new instance of demo class. 
and you are trying to get value from newly created demoFrame(that might be invisible for you but exist).

I'm hoping this will solve your issue.

Comment: Better to provide an accessor to get the text rather the exposing a component (or any class field) to possible misuse

Comment: I am working on a drag & drop gui, so when i drop JTextArea it got private access by default that was not editable so how can i change the access modifier to public.

Comment: @NuamanJamil It's nothing to do with access modifiers! Read the answer! You have two versions of JTextAreaDemo.

Comment: yes, I  looked into  his code later :) Actually he needs to change his question as well. :P

Answer (score 1):

You have two different instances of JTextAreaDemo!! One created in main and made visible, the other created in TxtArea_Class. The first one is the one on the screen, and the second is the one you read the string from. So the text you enter into the first doesn't show in the second.

Answer (score -1):

I got the contents of JTxtArea from another class by updating my code by this.

**TextArea_class**

```
  public TextArea_class(TextAreaDemo demo) {
  this.demo = demo;
  this.str = new String();
}
```

**JTxtAreaDemo**

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    TxtArea_Class d = new TxtArea_Class(this);
    d.readJtxtAreaText();


}
```